# By default Visual Studio puts output files in the source tree, how do I move them elsewhere?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

A default install of Visual Studio 2013 creates intermediate and output files in the source tree. This is makes housekeeping harder - I can't just nuke a whole directory to get rid of intermediate files, for example. It also makes it easy to accidentally add a whole bunch of said junk to source control by mistake.

How do you tell VS to put the files elsewhere?

Comment: What version control are you using? You can easily exclude the `bin` and `obj` folders by adding them to your `.tfignore`or `.gitignore` file.

Comment: @MEMark git and that was my initial thought too (and I think it was only a problem because I used sourcetree instead of VS's built in git client). Then I thought why not avoid the problem completely by moving the files elsewhere, because it's always bothered me that they were mixed in that way.

Comment: Fair enough. You could probably use a `.gitignore` file anyway though, since there are other files you don't want to commit, e.g. `*.csproj.user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At build time the locations of these files comes from the $(IntDir) and $(OutDir) build variables. These are defined by shared property sheet entries - shared as in shared by all projects built on a system. Updating that shared property sheet to put them elsewhere is a little tedious but only has to be done once.

For example, to change them such that intermediate files are placed in D:\Obj and output files are placed in D:\Exe:

- From the View menu, select PropertyManager.
- Expand any project node, e.g. MyProject.
- Expand any platform configuration node, e.g. Debug | Win32.
- Open the Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user property sheet.
- Select the General section
- Set the Intermediate Directory to (note the trailing backslash!)

  D:\Obj\$(SolutionName)\$(ProjectName)\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\
- Set the Output Directory to (note the trailing backslash!)

  D:\Exe\$(SolutionName)\$(ProjectName)\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\
- Repeat these steps for the remaining platform configuration nodes, e.g. Debug | x64

The property sheets are shared by different build types (e.g. debug, release) within a configuration, but not across platforms. This is why you have to repeat the steps for each platform (e.g. Win32 & x64). But you only have to do this for one project because they all use the same set of property sheets.

BEWARE!

There is a possible issue with this setup. Because the full drive and path is omitted from the directories, if you have more than one copy of a project/solution they will both try to write their output to the same location, possibly leading to horribleness.

Answer (score 1):

Open your proj file in a text editor, and look for something like this, depending on your platform/configuration:

```
<OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
```

Change it to whatever path you want it to be.

Comment: That would work, but only for a single project. My answer does it for every project built on that machine, even if the project comes from someone else.

Comment: The OP indicated that he wanted to nuke an entire directory which could be limited to Intermediate files, or the entirety of the source if a local copy was being used just to generate the deliverable. My answer works just fine for what was asked, and is a quick fix that can be done across vast amounts of directories with a simple Find and Replace using wildcards in say Notepad++, or scripts that look for prof files, for example. Not that anything is wrong with your answer, but nothing's wrong with mine, either.

Comment: I am the OP.  I was answering my own question just to have it somewhere I can Google easily. (My username is accurate!) Your answer is ok, but requires work for every project on the machine. Yes you could automate it, but that script would still have to be repeated for every new project. So I prefer my own answer still. Also I hate editing project files...